# PHP-Hooks: Different result on multiple hooks

Tags: php, hook

I'm using this library: **https://github.com/bainternet/PHP-Hooks** and seeking if anyone familiar with this library to look on my issue.

This is my code:

```
if (!function_exists('app_hooks')) {

    function app_hooks() {
        require_once("php-hooks.php");
        global $hooks;
        return $hooks;
    }

}

app_hooks()->add_filter('my_filter', function ($value) {
    echo $value; //output: some value to be passed
    return "x";
});
app_hooks()->add_filter('my_filter', function ($value) {
    echo $value; //output: xy (but should be 'some value to be passed')
    return "y";
});

$my_tabs = array();
$my_tabs[] = app_hooks()->apply_filters('my_filter', 'some value to be passed');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_tabs);
exit;
```

The **$my_tabs** is giving this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => y
)
```

**But I need both values like this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => x,
    [1] => y
)
```

Can anyone please inform me where am I wrong or if this is possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're only doing `my_tabs[] = something` once, how do you expect that to push two values onto the array?

Comment: That library hasn't been updated in 8 years, and the link to the website for more info is broken. I think it's been abandoned and you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I'm guessing that filters are processed sequentially, feeding the output of one as the input to the next, and the result you get is the last output. It doesn't combine them.

Comment: Think of it like a shell pipeline: `<input_file filter1 | filter2`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Can you please tell me what is the best thing I can do about this issue?

Comment: I'd suggest having an array of different hook names, and calling them in a loop to push each.

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a single hook will only push one value onto the array. You need to push in a loop to get multiple values, so I suggest giving different names to your hooks.

```
app_hooks()->add_filter('my_filter1', function ($value) {
    echo $value; //output: some value to be passed
    return "x";
});
app_hooks()->add_filter('my_filter2', function ($value) {
    echo $value; //output: xy (but should be 'some value to be passed')
    return "y";
});
$filters = ['my_filter1', 'my_filter2'];
foreach ($filters as $f) {
    $my_tabs[] = app_hooks()->apply_filters($f, 'some value to be passed');
}
```